# what is the simplest way to connect two computers over the internet using network cards

Tags: networking

If I wanted to share files with someone and I had a static IP what is the easiest way to give them access over the internet.  They dont have a static IP and I dont have a router.  Can I just let them access my system using the IP in my network card?

Comment: What exactly do you want to allow the other person to do with your computer? Remote desktop, sharing files, etc.

Comment: @Huskehn Cassy said "share files" right in her first sentence.

Comment: how many files? how often would they need access? how big are the files? what operating system are you running? What is your internet connection's upload bandwidth?

Answer (score 2):

Because you said "easiest", I'm going to recommend you use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) to create a shared folder and then add your friend to said folder.

Short of using commercial software (even though Dropbox is free for the first ~2GB), you'll need to look into something like setting up a web server or FTP server to share your files which will get considerably more complicated and have security implications.